# TOR/Firefox freeze on fresh Windows 8.1 install

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help, firefox, browsers

(yeah - I know - 8.1 sucks but I need this install for a work gig)

Just wiped a system, reinstalled w/ W8.1 (x64), 8 gigs of RAM, i5, SSD - runs like a champ. Downloaded TOR, saved it to my Downloads directory, ran to a couple of web pages and BAM - Firefox freeze, mouse freeze. Alt/tab still works but only to switch between applications. Only way to get mouse control back is to restart system. Tried removing TOR, wiping system, re-d/l'ed and allowed it to save to default location (Desktop), still freezes on first page.

Did a bit of searching, found this page:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hangs-or-not-responding#w_firefox-hangs-at-random-times

...tried most of the suggestions, still freezing.

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how to stop this from happening...

TIA

Comment: Does vanilla Firefox work without any problems?

Comment: Good question.  While I don't use FF as my default browser, I downloaded and ran Portable FF (trying to use a like-for-like example).  Runs fine, no issues.

Comment: Can you try starting the Tor Browser from the command line, and see if any useful logs are output? Something like: `C:\<path_to_tor>\Start Tor Browser.exe -v`, where the `-v` should mean something is output.

Comment: Ummmm...I'm hoping I don't sound too stupid here...I don't have a "start tor browser.exe" executable located anywhere in the expanded TorBrowser directory.  There's a .lnk file but that's just a shortcut that resolves out to "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe".  I tried running this in a command prompt window in both regular and with administrator privileges with the -v suffix (also with and without quotes) - and nothing happened. Nada.  Zip.